# does every app on the 21 platform need its own unique port?

Tags: bitcoin, ports

does every app running on the 21.co platform need its own unique port?

I am running several different applications on the 21.co bitcoin platform and I notice that each software developer assigns their own port numbers.  Often the default is 5000.  Can I have several apps all sharing the same port?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Per 21 support on the 21co.slack.com channel, every unique app requires a unique port number.  There are at present no facilities for managing port assignment.